# UITabBar Background image and bar item icon's size and position is strange in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I embedded UITabBarViewController into UIViewController in storyboard  and i customise the background of tab bar and icon of tab bar item. But they looked strange.Tab bar's height is doubled and icon size of tab bar item is a little big. I use iPhone 5c with OS iOS 7 to test. 
Background image of tab bar is 640*98 px.Icon of tab bar item is 50*50 px.
Here is the reference image.
[image]

Comment: you must be using the wrong sizes of image

Comment: @DeepK Background image of tab bar is 640*98 px.Icon of tab bar item is 50*50 px.

Comment: Can you share your code? and what is the size of your image?

Comment: @VineeshTP I didn't wright code yet. I use storyboard to embed tab bar.Background image of tab bar is 640*98 px.Icon of tab bar item is 50*50 px.

Comment: you should have to set a fit image to tabbar item

Comment: @VineeshTP My image size is right.According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. Rename image with @2x.